# Cleaner way to write this sort function

Tags: javascript

I cant think of a cleaner way to write this function - I wanted to have a ternary which switched the > depending on whether the type of ASCENDING or DECENDING however you can not seem to do that .  Obviously repeating myself and and know this is not good but cant think of another way at moment.

```
name: ((studies, type) => {
    let sortedStudies = studies;
    if (type === 'ASCENDING') {
      sortedStudies = studies.sort((a, b) => {
       let nameA = a.name.toUpperCase();
       let nameB = b.name.toUpperCase();
        if (nameA < nameB) {
          return -1;
        }
        if (nameA > nameB) {
          return 1;
        }
        return 0;
      });
    } else {
      sortedStudies = studies.sort((a, b) => {
       let nameA = a.name.toUpperCase();
       let nameB = b.name.toUpperCase();
        if (nameA > nameB) {
          return -1;
        }
        if (nameA < nameB) {
          return 1;
        }
        return 0;
      });
    }
    return sortedStudies
  })
```

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com is the more appropriate site to use for questions like these. I'd suggest moving the `type` check within your `sort` function to reduce the amount of code.

Comment: Maybe sort ascending by default, and if descending, then [reverse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse)?

Comment: Side note: be aware than `sort` mutates the array (and returns it).

Comment: `const modifier = (type === "ASCENDING") ? 1 : -1; /*...*/ return nameA.localeCompare(nameB) * modifier;`

Answer (score 0):

That's the best version that I can write without modifying your logic of work (except that I clone the array to avoid mutating the original one):

```
name: ((studies, type) => {
        let sortedStudies = studies.slice(0);
        if (type === 'ASCENDING')
            return sortedStudies.sort((a, b) => {
                let ans = a.name.toUpperCase() < b.name.toUpperCase() ? -1 : -2;
                return ans === -1 ? ans : Number(a.name.toUpperCase() > b.name.toUpperCase());
            });
        return sortedStudies.sort((a, b) => {
            let ans = a.name.toUpperCase() < b.name.toUpperCase() ? -1 : -2;
            return ans === -1 ? ans : Number(a.name.toUpperCase() < b.name.toUpperCase());
        });
    })
```